# How to print total time of sql execution using django debug toolbar debugsqlshell

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-debug-toolbar

I found `debugsqlshell` from django toolbar, which you can run wiht manage.py as alternative to standard shell and I want to test performance of queries on nested objects.

I see certian outputs on each of queries, but how can I get the sum of time which elapsed on all of them?

Below two methods, which time I would like to compare.

```
def stands(self):
    stands = []
    for stand in Stand.objects.all():
        if stand.room.floor.building.fair.pk == self.pk:
            stands.append(stand)

    return stands
```

ans second using `prefetch_related`:

```
def stands3(self):
    stands = []
    for stand in Stand.objects.all().prefetch_related('room__floor__building__fair'):
        if stand.room.floor.building.fair.pk == self.pk:
            stands.append(stand)

    return stands
```

Thanks to proposed by joel-goldstick `cProfile` I managed to get some exact numbers:

stands():

```
11 685 649 function calls (10 532 897 primitive calls) in 9.861 seconds
```

stands3() using `prefetch_related`:

```
1 855 483 function calls (1 839 617 primitive calls) in 1.295 seconds
```

But still geting this numbers from debugshell will be cool, so don't bother to answer if you know how to do that.

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual

Comment: Looks very promising, will test IT!